# Event Hub Checkpoint Not Fetching Events Until Server Restart

Tags: azure, azure-eventhub

My async consumer fetching the data from the Event Hub. I am updating the checkpoint after every event processing. When any error/exception is raised while processing the event then not updating the checkpoint. So that we can get the same event later and we'll not skip those events. But, we are not getting these processing failed events until we did a server restart.

Once the server restarts we are getting the new events along with events that are not checkpointed.

Is there any way we can get them (Events that are not checkpointed) without restart?

And also I am confused a little with checkpoint behavior. For suppose

```
Event 1 is processed. Checkpoint.
Event 2 throws an exception.
Event 3 throws an exception.
Event 4 is processed. Checkpoint.
```

Now whenever the server restarts, the checkpoint is past Event 2 and 3, and therefore they will never be reprocessed. But, how come they are coming back again when the server restart as the checkpoint is updated at Event 4, it should fetch from Event 4 right?

Comment: Can you tell us which partition each event was in?   All activity in Event Hubs happens on a per-partition basis.   You're checkpointing Events 1 and 4.   That may create one checkpoint that gets updated or it may exist as two separate checkpoints, depending on the partitions involved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is "not from the same consumer."

Event Hubs is an event stream that can be read in a forward-only manner; you cannot rewind the stream and re-read events in-place.  To rewind, you have to create a new link and specify an earlier starting position in the stream.

The consumer clients from the Event Hubs SDK read the events and emit them to your code for processing.  Each event read is emitted once - its the responsibility of the processing code to judge how to do so.  If your processing fails in a manner that you deem transient, ensuring retries for that event should be done as part of the processing logic, as would any form of dead-lettering for events that you would like to revisit later.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, Jesse. So we can't do it from the same consumer until we restart the server. But as there is no concept of a dead letter queue in Event Hub SDK, can you suggest to me any intermediate retry process mechanisms( to hold failed events data ) other than databases.

Comment: The answer to your core question remains the same;  you can't rewind the stream in a consumer.  That said, depending on which partitions events belong to and whether ownership of those partitions is migrating between processors, you could see those events again, based on your updated context.